# Facebook Marketing API : Get results and cost per result of a Campaign

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

I'm creating an application (using Facebook Business Java SDK) that can get all infomation of campaigns own by an Ad Account. Almost of my campaigns have same objective is APP_INSTALLS. I want to know how many time my app was installed, so I tried to request infomation like "Results" column and "Cost per Result" column in Adsmanager board :

[Adsmanager colums](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrE10.png)

But when I added "results" and "cost_per_result" to APIRequestGetInsights's request fields, I got a FailRequestException :

"{"error":{"message":"(#100) results, cost_per_result are not valid for fields param. please check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ads-insights/ for all valid values","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"DnPCKyIGIqs"}}"

I used an user access token with permissions below :
- read_insights
- manage_pages
- pages_show_list
- publish_pages
- ads_management
- ads_read
- business_management

I searched on google many times but nothing is useful. So someone here please tell me how to get "Results" and "Cost per Result" info of a campaign by Facebook api?

Comment: I am also interested in this. These values used to be available under `cost_per_action_type` before 3.2, but have been removed from here. I found out that using a non-system user token, with permissions user_friends, publish_actions, read_insights, whitelisted_offline_access, manage_pages, pages_show_list, publish_pages, ads_management, ads_read, business_management, public_profile will let you access this field, but no luck using a system user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in the comment, this information used to be available in the field `cost_per_action_type`, you could retrieve the value in the item where `ad['action_type'] == 'mobile_app_install'`.

Unfortunately, this is no longer available in 3.2, but you can calculate this value yourself:

Make the query including the `actions` and `spend` fields.
You'll find the total number of installs (in the item with the `action_type == 'mobile_app_install')`, then you can calculate the cost per install with `cost_per_install = spend / install_count`.